# Submit form with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple form for uploading a file.  If I use an ordinary submit button, everything works as expected:

```
<form id="mainform" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Analyze File"/>
</form>
```

But if I change it to an ordinary button and use Javascript to submit the form, nothing happens:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Analyze File" onclick="document.getElementById('mainform').submit()"/>
```

I verified that the onclick handler really is getting called, and looking up the form works correctly.  For example, if I change it to `onclick="alert(document.getElementById('mainform').action)"`, the alert comes up as expected and shows the target URL of the form.  But for some reason, the call to submit() simply doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @kol: w3schools is not a good source for JavaScript code.  Plus, how does his code differ from that?  He's pretty much doing the same thing,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is your `submit` button. Its id is `submit`, which means that `document.getElementById("mainform").submit` represents the button with ID of `submit`, not the `submit` function.

You just need to change the ID for that button, and you're all good.

Answer (score 5):

You have a naming conflict between the `.submit()` method and the:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Analyze File"/>
```

By having that `id`, a reference to it is being assigned to the `submit` property of the `<form>`, which replaces the method.

If you rename the `<input>`, you should be able to `.submit()` as expected:

```
<input type="submit" id="mainform_submit" value="Analyze File"/>
```